# Can't connect to PostgreSQL docker container via psycopg2.connect from my VM

Tags: python, postgresql, containers, virtual-machine, psycopg2

I'm trying to connect in my VM to a container's PostgreSQL database via psycopg2.connec to insert a csv file as a table but I keep  encountering this error:

```
Failed to connect to PostgreSQL: connection to server at "postgres" (container's IP), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Where "postgres" is the name of the service that contains my database. This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"
services:

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=IP
      - POSTGRES_USER=pids
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pids

  ingesta:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: datos_est/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

Where DATABASE_HOST=IP is the IP of my virtual machine
This is the Dockerfile that is built in 'ingesta' service:

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /app

COPY datos_est/example.py datos_est/example.csv /app/

RUN pip install psycopg2

CMD ["python3", "example.py"]
```

These are the params of the psycopg2.connect command of my example.py file:

```
conexion = psycopg2.connect(
    host="postgres",
    database="postgres",
    user="pids",
    password="pids",
)
```

This is my file explorer so you don't get lost with the paths of my files:

> P3/
>
> > src/
> >
> > > docker-compose.yml
> > > datos_est/
> > >
> > > > Dockerfile
> > > > example.csv
> > > > example.py

I'm running the `docker compose up` from my VM
I also put the `depends_on` parameter to the 'ingesta' service so it starts after 'postgres' service is done starting.
I have tried adding a `time.sleep(10)` before the 'conexion' variable. It didn't work 100% of the times.
I made sure the name of the host in my script matches with the name of the service that has the database.
I made sure to have a clean environment so I don't have issues with other containers or images:

```
docker container rm -f $(docker container ls -aq)
docker image rm -f $(docker image ls -q)
```

I made sure that I can access the database from the terminal using:

```
ubuntu@pids-vm:~/P3/src$ psql -h localhost -U pids -d pids -p 5432
Password for user pids: 
psql (14.9 (Ubuntu 14.9-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), server 16.1 (Debian 16.1-1.pgdg120+1))
WARNING: psql major version 14, server major version 16.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.

pids=#
```

I also checked if de database was listening to 5432 and it looks like it is:

```
ubuntu@pids-vm:~/P3/src$ netstat -nl |grep 5432
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Do you have any suggestions on what is going wrong?

Comment: Change the `host` in the `psycopg2` connection from `postgres` to `localhost`?

Comment: Still have the same error. The thing is PostgreSQL database is in the `postgres` container so if I put `localhost` rather than `postgres` its looking for the database in my virtual machine instead of the container

Comment: Then you need to explain: *I made sure that I can access the database from the terminal using: psql -h localhost -U pids -d pids -p 5432*.  Is that indeed reaching the database you want to reach in your `psycopg2` script?

Comment: Wait you are right. Thats not the database where I'm doing stuff in my python script. The correct database is postgres which is specified in the docker-compose.yml

Comment: 1) You need to clear up your question on that point. 2) You need to sort out terms. In a new Postgres server installation(cluster) there are three databases installed by default(template0, template1, postgres). So what you want is to connect to the `Postgres cluster that is running on the host `postgres` and listening on `port 5432` and use the `postgres` database there vs the one that is running at `localhost`.

Comment: If you have a Postgres instance running in the VM on port 5432 and one running in the Docker container on port 5432 and you are exposing the Docker Postgres port in the VM I see a conflict. There can only be one Postgres instance running on a given port at a time. The second one to start will error out on the common port.

Comment: I only want one database. That is the one inside the docker container.

I have created a pgadmin container to manage better what is going on. When I add a new server with the `hostname/adress = postgres` being 'postgres' the name of the service of the postgresql container, I get two databases. One is 'postgres' and the other is 'pids'. I can tell that I'm inserting data to the 'postgres' database but I'm not sure why 'pids' is created.

Comment: You don't want to use the  `postgres`  database for your application. It's primary purpose is to be a 'default' database to connect to for tools like pgAdmin4.  You need to create your own database for your application.  That would seem to be what `pids` is as that is created by the Postgres `initdb`.  This conversation is getting out of scope for a SO question. I would advise you reading [Postgres tutorial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial.html) before going much further.

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared a network in your docker-compose file, so you won't be able to access the host over the network via a hostname.

You have mapped a port from the docker host into the docker container, but you can't access that from inside ingesta by using "localhost", as within a container "localhost" refers to the container itself, not the container's host.  So you would have to refer to the docker host from inside the container by its ip address, which is traditionally 172.17.0.1.  Your psql works with 'localhost' only because you are running it directly on the docker host.

> Where DATABASE_HOST=IP is the IP of my virtual machine

As far as I know, DATABASE_HOST doesn't do anything in a postgresql image.  Also, how can you know what IP will be assigned when it has not yet been assigned?

Comment: So what you are saying is that DATABASE_HOST is'nt declaring anything in my postgresql image?
And if I do a `docker exec` to reach the docker container of 'postgres' and then try to connect with psql, I won't be able to connect to it?

Comment: Also my intention is that I only have one postgresql database and it's the one inside the docker container of 'postgres' service. I'm not sure but I have two diferent databases. I explain everything in the comments above.

Comment: @BlasSicilia I've never seen DATABASE_HOST used before, I suspect it does nothing.  Is that from some documentation or tutorial?  Maybe it does something when set on the client, but that isn't where you have it set.

Comment: @BlasSicilia If you docker exec into the postgres container, you should be able to connect to the database with psql, either over the local socket connection or via localhost.  But the 'postgres' container is not the 'ingesta' container, so this probably won't do you much good.